# Change Tomcat Address on my localhost

Tags: url, tomcat, web-deployment

On my Tomcat, I have an HTML page.

I need to type the following address to make it run:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/BiddingSystem/BiddingSystem.html

but I want it to be accessed using this address:  www.moribiz.com

Is this possible just by changing some setting on Tomcat?

Comment: running on win or linux or... ?

Comment: @FelicePollano.. if it is in linux how can we handle this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure the host properties in Tomcat's `server.xml`, and can make an alias to the default `localhost` host:

```xml
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" 
            autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Alias>www.moribiz</Alias>
</Host>
```

For more information, see [Tomcat's configuration manual](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/host.html).

Comment: can I separate multiple virtual host using port numbers? like name="localhost:8020"?

Answer (score 14):

I have Eclipse EE and Tomcat7, and I need to run my servlets not at `localhost:8080`, but on a pretty domain :)

I have made it this way:

1. In file `%windows%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` add:

   ```
   127.0.0.10 tomcat
   ```
2. In file `%workspace%\Servers\Tomcat 7` at `localhost-config\Server.xml`

```xml
    <Connector port="80" address="127.0.0.10" connectionTimeout="20000"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
    <Engine defaultHost="tomcat" name="Catalina">
        <Host name="tomcat" appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true">
        ...
        </Host>
    </Engine>
```

Now my Apache Tomcat works fine (I hope) at `http://tomcat/` and at same time my Apache2+PHP works at `http://localhost/`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at item 4 of [O'Reilly's Tomcat tips](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html):

```xml
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" debug="0">
    <Service name="Tomcat-Standalone">
        <Connector className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector"
                port="8080" minProcessors="5" maxProcessors="75"
                enableLookups="true" redirectPort="8443"/>
        <Connector className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector"
                port="8443" minProcessors="5" maxProcessors="75"
                acceptCount="10" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"/>
        <Factory className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteServerSocketFactory"
                clientAuth="false" protocol="TLS" />
        </Connector>
        <Engine name="Standalone" defaultHost="localhost" debug="0">
        <!-- This Host is the default Host -->
        <Host name="localhost" debug="0" appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Context path="" docBase="ROOT" debug="0"/>
            <Context path="/orders" docBase="/home/ian/orders" debug="0"
                        reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
            </Context>
        </Host>

        <!-- This Host is the first "Virtual Host": www.example.com -->
        <Host name="www.example.com" appBase="/home/example/webapp">
            <Context path="" docBase="."/>
        </Host>

        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

The relevant part is where the virtual host is defined (in the last `<Host>` tag).

Comment: Please don't just post a link. Use the relevant information as an answer and post the link only as reference. Thanks.