# How to stop redirecting the URL to localhost

Tags: java, tomcat

I have installed the tomcat server in windows. I have added the `test.example.com` string in hosts file so I can access tomcat console using the `localhost:8080` and also `test.example.com:8080.`

Then I deployed a war file in webapps folder. Now, I can access the application using the URL `localhost:8080/test` and `test.example.com:8080/test`.

Here, When I access `test.example.com:8080/test` the URL is redirecting to login page as `localhost:8080/test/UI/Login` but I want it to be `test.example.com:8080/test/UI/Login`

Can anyone suggest me how to access with out localhost and without updating the existing war file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Tomcat Address on my localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132959/change-tomcat-address-on-my-localhost)